# How to call a function only after getting response from API in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, api

I have used Expandable List view.

I have to call `loadData()` only after there has been response from Api. Putting it inside `Handler` is reporting a blank activity after the launch of app. All this is being done in MainActivity. API calls can be found in the function `apiCalls()`.Putting Handler inside api call is again giving error while loading the activity.

Here is my Code:

```
    package com.example.expandablelistview;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(MainActivity.this);

    private LinkedHashMap<String, GroupInfo> subjects = new LinkedHashMap<String, GroupInfo>();
    private ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList = new ArrayList<GroupInfo>();

    private CustomAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView simpleExpandableListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // add data for displaying in expandable list view


        //get reference of the ExpandableListView
        simpleExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleExpandableListView);
        // create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
        listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, deptList);
        // attach the adapter to the expandable list view
        simpleExpandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        // expandAll();

        if (Utility.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            apiCall();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Internet not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (dbManager.checkTablesInitialsed() == true) {
        loadData();
        }
    }

    private void apiCall() {
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser(this);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Searching...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 8000);
        if (dbManager.checkTablesInitialsed() == false) {

            Ion.with(this).load(Constant.URL_CLASS).setTimeout(8000).asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String response) {

                            if (e != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!Problem establishing connection with the server- class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("Exception.class..", e + "");

                            } else {
                                try {
                                    Log.e("RESPONSE ..class", response);
                                    JsonParser.getDataFromServer_class(response);
                                    //  Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Count" + wordBean.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } catch (Exception parseException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error hitting the API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Search...class   ", parseException.toString());
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
            Ion.with(this).load(Constant.URL_SECTION).setTimeout(8000).asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String response) {

                            if (e != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!Problem establishing connection with the server-  SECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("Exception...SECTION", e + "");

                            } else {
                                try {
                                    Log.e("RESPONSE .SECTION.", response);
                                    JsonParser.getDataFromServer_section(response);
                                    //  Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Count" + wordBean.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } catch (Exception parseException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error hitting the API SECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Search...SECTION", parseException.toString());
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
            Ion.with(this).load(Constant.URL_SUBJECT).setTimeout(8000).asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String response) {

                            if (e != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!Problem establishing connection with the server- SUBJECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("Exception..SUBJECT", e + "");

                            } else {
                                try {
                                    Log.e("RESPONSE ..SUBJECT", response);
                                    JsonParser.getDataFromServer_subject(response);

                                    //  Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Count" + wordBean.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (Exception parseException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error hitting the API SUBJECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Search...SUBJECT ", parseException.toString());
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
            Ion.with(this).load(Constant.URL_TIMETABLE).setTimeout(8000).asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String response) {

                            if (e != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!Problem establishing connection with the server- TIMETABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("Exception..TIMETABLE.", e + "");

                            } else {
                                try {
                                    Log.e("RESPONSE ..TIMETABLE", response);
                                    JsonParser.getDataFromServer_timetable(response);

                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    //  Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Count" + wordBean.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } catch (Exception parseException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error hitting the API TIMETABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Search.. TIMETABLE  ", parseException.toString());
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    //method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            simpleExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }

    //method to collapse all groups
    private void collapseAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            simpleExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }

    private void loadData() {
        int i, k = 1, size = 0, j = 0;
        String ar[] = {"", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        ArrayList<WordBean> arrayList;
        WordBean wordBean;
        String str;
        for (i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
            arrayList = dbManager.getTimetable(i);
            j = 0;
            k = 1;
            size = arrayList.size();
          // Log.e("classs", "" + size);
            while (j < size) {
                wordBean = arrayList.get(j);
                if (wordBean.getLectureNo().equals(k + "")) {
                    str = " Class:" + wordBean.getClassName() + " Sec:" + wordBean.getSectionName() + " Sub:" + wordBean.getSubName();
                    j++;
                } else {
                    str = "FREE--";
                }

                addProduct(ar[i], "Lecture " + k + " :" + str);
                k++;
            }

            while (k <= 8) {
                addProduct(ar[i], "Lecture " + k + " :" + "FREE--");
                k++;
            }
        }


    }


    //here we maintain our products in various departments
    private int addProduct(String department, String product) {

        int groupPosition = 0;

        //check the hash map if the group already exists
        GroupInfo headerInfo = subjects.get(department);
        //add the group if doesn't exists
        if (headerInfo == null) {
            headerInfo = new GroupInfo();
            headerInfo.setName(department);
            subjects.put(department, headerInfo);
            deptList.add(headerInfo);
        }

        //get the children for the group
        ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = headerInfo.getProductList();
        //size of the children list
        int listSize = productList.size();
        //add to the counter
        listSize++;

        //create a new child and add that to the group
        ChildInfo detailInfo = new ChildInfo();
        detailInfo.setSequence(String.valueOf(listSize));
        detailInfo.setName(product);
        productList.add(detailInfo);
        headerInfo.setProductList(productList);

        //find the group position inside the list
        groupPosition = deptList.indexOf(headerInfo);
        return groupPosition;
    }

}

    enter code here
```

Comment: What is this `Ion` thing?

Comment: it is the part of Koushik Datta's library.